# Where is documentation on Rdefines.h functions and macros?

Tags: c, r

This seems like it should be a simple thing, but I'm having a heck of a time tracking down documentation on R's `Rdefines.h` header file for C.  To the extent that I've looked over the Writing R Extensions manual, I've found some examples using functions and macros apparently defined in the header, but I haven't found an exhaustive list with documentation.

Where can I find this documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Writing R Extensions" manual you already consulted is all there is, apart from the source code and other packages using it.

As far as I know Simon is working on a book too but til that is done ... you get to study the manual, and the sources.